# Testing a CakePHP 3 REST API

Tags: api, testing, cakephp-3.0, jwt

I am developing an API on CakePHP 3 using the CRUD Plugin and ADmad's JWT plugin. I've created fixtures for all tables by importing the schema and then defining some dummy records. Now I'd like to know the best way to test my API.

Namely:

1. How do I set an Authorized user in my tests?
2. How do I call API methods in the test framework?

I don't have any code to show at the moment because I'm really not sure how to go about this in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

The one way I see to test API endpoints is by using `post()` method of the IntegrationTestCase suite. A very basic example:

```
public function testLogin()
{
    // You can add this to the setUp() function to make it global
    $this->configRequest([
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ]
    ]);

    $this->post('/auth/token', ['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->assertResponseContains('access_token');
}
```

Store that access token (or pre-generate one) & use that to set authorization header.

You can send your authorization tokens like so (before **EVERY** request):

```
$this->configRequest([
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token
        ]
    ]);
```

**TIP**: You can `Configure::write()` the `Security.salt` values in `bootstrap.php` of the test - this way the password salting works! I also found saving the salted password value in your fixture helpful.

More details in [CakePHP Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html).

Comment: How do I store the token in the tests?